# finding consecutive letters in a string python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, recursion

Hi I'm trying to print out a substring of a passed string if two letters follow each other on the alphabet. i.e 'asdfhi' -> h i

Here is what I have so far. I am trying to write this function recursively but cannot seem to get the function to iterate through the string. I know I am doing something wrong please help. Currently the function just goes on an infinite loop using the first set of indeces and spits out the result of check the first two letters in the string, but never leaves that state.

```
def findSubstr(s):
    count=1
    while len(s) >= count:
        alpha='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
        alphaIndex = alpha.index(s[count])
        #print(s[count-1])
        #print(alpha[alphaIndex-1])
        #print(s[count-1] == alpha[alphaIndex-1])
        if(s[count] in alpha):
            if(s[count-1] == alpha[alphaIndex-1]):
                print(s[count-1], s[count])
    count=count+1
    findSubstr(s)
```

Comment: post a few representative input strings and expected result for each of them

Comment: delete the last line `findSubstr(s)`, and from there on, solve your problem . It will no longer be a recursive  solution, but you will get a working solution much quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to iterate through the string, let the python do that for you -- it's much faster and more effective. Try this:

```
from string import ascii_letters

def find_consecutive(s) :
    for a,b in zip(ascii_letters, ascii_letters[1:]) :
        if a+b in s :
            print( a, b)
```

testing:

```
>>> find_consecutive('asdfhi')
h i
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Python actually offers `ord` function that returns the integer representation of a caracter, in other words you can use the [Ascii table](https://www.w3resource.com/w3r_images/python-basic-image-exercise-86.png).

> [ord()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord):
>
> Given a string of length one, return an integer representing the
>   Unicode code point of the character when the argument is a unicode
>   object, or the value of the byte when the argument is an 8-bit string

So, you can do something like this:

```
def consecultive(inp_str):
    for k, v in zip(inp_str, inp_str[1:]):
        if ord(v) - ord(k) == 1:
            yield k, v

a = 'asdfhi'
list(consecultive(a))
```

Output:

```
[('h', 'i')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function works if you just fix the indentation levels and remove the = from your while statement. The reason it loops forever is because you're currently increasing your count outside of the while loop.

```
s = 'asdfhi'

def findSubstr(s):
    count=1
    while len(s) > count:
        alpha='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
        alphaIndex = alpha.index(s[count])
        #print(s[count-1])
        #print(alpha[alphaIndex-1])
        #print(s[count-1] == alpha[alphaIndex-1])
        if(s[count] in alpha):
            if(s[count-1] == alpha[alphaIndex-1]):
                print(s[count-1], s[count])
        count=count+1

findSubstr(s) # h i
```